# How to create multiple resources with one Request in Spring Data Rest?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-rest

What do I need to implement in order to create multiple records in my DB with a single http request?

I have a small Web-Application using SpringDataRest and JPA/Hibernate in which I can create resources with requests like this:

```
curl -XPUT -H"Content-Type: application/json; charset utf-8"\
-d'{"id":"1","type":"test"}'\
http://localhost:8080/test/items/1
```

Instead, I would like to do something like:

```
curl -XPUT -H"Content-Type: application/json; charset utf-8"\
-d'[{"id":"1","type":"test1"},{"id":"2","type":"test2"}]'\ 
http://localhost:8080/test/items/
```

The according Repository looks like this:

```
@RestResource(path = "items", rel = "items")
public interface ItemRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Item, String> {
}
```

The Bean used:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement(name = "page")
@Table(name="page")
public class Item {

@Id
@Column(name="id")
private String id;

@Column(name="type")
private String type;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * @return the type
 */
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

/**
 * @param type the type to set
 */
public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}   
}
```

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: I get an Http error when PUTting the data. Using POST, only the first record is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a controller.

Essentially you want to override the POST method on the resource to accept a list of items instead of a single one.

You'll have to get reference to your repository inside the controller and insert the objects manually.