# Spring Data rest how to perform CRUD on @manytomany relation ,composite table with extra column

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am unable to perform CRUD via json POST from restful client Postman on Composite table having extra column .I am using Spring boot ,spring data rest and spring JPA.
 I have 3 tables in data base 

-user

-competency

-user_competency (join/composite table with extra column)

[image]

Here are my classes

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "\"user\"", schema = "public")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, 
          property = "userId")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long userId;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    private Set<UserCompetency> userCompetencies = new HashSet<UserCompetency>(0);

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<UserCompetency> getUserCompetencies() {
        return this.userCompetencies;
    }

    public void setUserCompetencies(Set<UserCompetency> userCompetencies) {
        this.userCompetencies = userCompetencies;
    }

}
```

**Competency**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "competency", schema = "public")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, 
          property = "competencyId")
public class Competency implements java.io.Serializable {


    private Long competencyId;
    private Set<UserCompetency> userCompetencies = new HashSet<UserCompetency>(0);

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)

    @Column(name = "competency_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Long getCompetencyId() {
        return this.competencyId;
    }

    public void setCompetencyId(Long competencyId) {
        this.competencyId = competencyId;
    }

        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "competency")
    public Set<UserCompetency> getUserCompetencies() {
        return this.userCompetencies;
    }

    public void setUserCompetencies(Set<UserCompetency> userCompetencies) {
        this.userCompetencies = userCompetencies;
    }
}
```

**UserCompetency**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_competency", schema = "public")
@JsonIdentityInfo(
          generator =ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, 
          property = "id")
public class UserCompetency implements java.io.Serializable {
    private UserCompetencyId id;
    private Level level;
    private User user;
    private Competency competency;

    @EmbeddedId

    @AttributeOverrides({
            @AttributeOverride(name = "competencyId", column = @Column(name = "competency_id", nullable = false)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "userId", column = @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)) })
    public UserCompetencyId getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(UserCompetencyId id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "level_id")
    public Level getLevel() {
        return this.level;
    }

    public void setLevel(Level level) {
        this.level = level;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "competency_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Competency getCompetency() {
        return this.competency;
    }

    public void setCompetency(Competency competency) {
        this.competency = competency;
    }
}
```

**UserCompetencyId**

```
@Embeddable
public class UserCompetencyId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long competencyId;
    private Long userId;

    public UserCompetencyId() {
    }

    public UserCompetencyId(Long competencyId, Long userId) {
        this.competencyId = competencyId;
        this.userId = userId;
    }


    @Column(name = "competency_id", nullable = false)
    public Long getCompetencyId() {
        return this.competencyId;
    }

    public void setCompetencyId(Long competencyId) {
        this.competencyId = competencyId;
    }

    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    public Long getUserId() {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if ((this == other))
            return true;
        if ((other == null))
            return false;
        if (!(other instanceof UserCompetencyId))
            return false;
        UserCompetencyId castOther = (UserCompetencyId) other;

        return (this.getCompetencyId() == castOther.getCompetencyId()) && (this.getUserId() == castOther.getUserId());
    }    
}
```

Suppose i have already record in User and Competency tables and i want to assocaite both i am trying to post like this ,but it give me error of 405 Method Not Allowed.

[image]
help required ,what should be structure of json to be posted User will already exist and competency will might exist or new can be added and associated with existing user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code I was able to post a new relation:

**UserCompetency.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_competency")
@IdClass(UserCompetencyId.class)
public class UserCompetency implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "competency_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Competency competency;

    @Id @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;
```

**UserCompetencyId.class**

```
public class UserCompetencyId implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long competency;

    private Long user;

    public UserCompetencyId() {
    }

    public UserCompetencyId(Long competency, Long user) {
        this.competency = competency;
        this.user = user;
    }
```

**UserCompetencyRepository.class**

```
public interface UserCompetencyRepository extends JpaRepository<UserCompetency, UserCompetencyId> {

}
```

**POST** http://localhost:8080/userCompetencies

```
{
    "competency": "/competencies/2"
    , "user": "/user/4"
}
```

Comment: It worked out data is saving to composite table,but my UserCompetency class have one other property,so I have other column in table i.e level_id ,which is also foreign key,given in question at top screen shoot ,kindly look at it and now how should I post level id  in json post     
        private UserCompetencyId id;
 private Level level;
 private User user;
 private Competency competency;

Comment: Adding `, "level": "/level/123"`?

Comment: ok got it,actually repository class was not exposed for Level and facing problem ,one thing more i need to ask is that , what if I have an existing user and i want to add new competency so that it save to competency table  and associate it to existing user in 1 go via json post,how i will do it.

Comment: Would be also a custom controller. Or two REST-calls. One for getting the new Id of the `competency` and then one for posting the new `userCompetencies` relation.

Comment: How will I perform Update and delete on userCompetencies ,composite table

Comment: is it possible to add multiple competencies to existing user ,via single json post,currently its adding 1 competency to 1 user

Comment: multiple resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32053092/how-to-create-multiple-resources-with-one-request-in-spring-data-rest

Comment: Could you add another question for update and delete?

Comment: Although objects are saving with this implementation but now i came across an issue and that is Spring HATEOAS embedded resource object.I cant read retrieve values of user or competency, when i try to call http://localhost:8181/api/userCompetencies ,it show me objects internal values not the real values ,how can i retrieve that.

Comment: Please add another SO question on this and link it here!

Comment: Here i have added another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43399225/unable-to-retrieve-spring-hateoas-embedded-resource-object-in-case-of-manytoman

Comment: kindly suggest how can I update and delete record from composite table user_competency.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there seems to be no "natural/easy" way to get what you want. But there is a promissing project for integrating embeddables by extending the serialization process: https://github.com/gregturn/embeddable-spring-data-rest

- `UserCompetencyIdJacksonModule`, `UserCompetencyIdSerializer`, ..

Then you should be able **PATCH** (not **POST**) your JSON from above.

Comment: I have download this project and tried to replicate same changes ,i came across an issue when i use @Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class) on main class ,the api endpoints are not accessible and when i access http://localhost:8080/api it give 404 not found error

Comment: The `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration` wouldn'd be need I think. But the other stuff doesn't help you either. So I added a new answer.. The other problem we had last week.. Where you able to solve it?

Comment: thanks.that problem I solved via implementing custom controller function.